# Retrieve data from dynamically created controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am dynamically creating several dropdown list on the selection changed event of a main (static) dropdown list. These are created in The `TableCell` of default `Table`. When submit button is clicked I need to load a new page with selected values of dropdown as parameters. Basically I need to get the dropdown results in the second page.

This is how dropboxes are created:

```
    while (reader.Read())
    { 
        pcID = int.Parse(reader["fk_pcID"].ToString());
        pcDesc = GetpcDescription(pcID);
        List<Product> prodList = GetProductsBypcID(pcID);
        DropDownList ddList = new DropDownList();
        ddList.ID = "ddlPC" + pcID;
        foreach(Product prod in prodList)
        {
            ddList.Items.Add(new ListItem(prod.ProductName, prod.ProductID.ToString()));
        }
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        cell1.Text = pcDesc;

        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        cell2.Controls.Add(ddList);

        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        row.Cells.Add(cell1);
        row.Cells.Add(cell2);

        table.Rows.Add(row);  
    }
```

EDIT: The above code runs at the selection changed event of a dropdown which is set to runat server. But dynamically created dropdowns are not set to run at server

Comment: Please don't prefix questions with "ASP.NET:". On [so], we use tags to categorize questions.

Comment: if you're having problems retrieving the values on postback, chances are you are creating your dynamic controls too late in your page lifecycle. Try adding them when your webform is initialized (OnInit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these drop-down boxes `runat="server"`? Meaning: did you created them programmaticly via a .net post-back event through the code behind? If so, just get the selected value the same as you would with any other control, and then pass it through a query string or a cookie.

Are these standard html drop-down lists? Good luck reading them from a code-behind. That gets you all tangled up in the viewstate, and while technically possible, is realistically not feasible.

If the second option is the case, it might be a much better option to have your button target a JavaScript function that gets the selected values and then passes them via querystring. Then on the other page you can read the querystrings from the code-behind, or on the client-side.

Comment: No, putting the selected value in a cookie is a horrible idea. This can be handled with a proper understanding of the page lifecycle.

Comment: The above code runs at the selection changed event of a dropdown which is set to runat server. But dynamically created dropdowns are not set to run at server.

Comment: Why is this a horrible idea? Example: "Select your Language [english, spanish, german]" Would not a cookie be the *best* place for this type of information?  He doesn't give any clues about the content of the dropdown (until edit). So a cookie is an equally valid way as any to store data across pages.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good candidate for the DynamicControlsPlaceholder. It will preserve your dynamic controls automatically, without requiring any additional code on the page. If you need to create the controls OnSelectedIndexChanged, I think this might be the simplest solution.

It's a free component, and you can download it here.

http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx